# Fragment is overlapping on activity :Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, overlapping

As soon as i click the button on the activity to call the fragment so that it replaces the activity with the new fragment , it does not replaces the activity with the fragment but the content of the fragment overlaps on the activity.

Here is kotlin file of activity:

```
package com.sahil.randoms
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_game_start.*

class ActivityGameStart : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_start)


        title="Start"

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(){

            frameStart.removeAllViews()

            val fragmentManager= supportFragmentManager
            val transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            transaction.replace(R.id.frameStart,FragmentPlayArea()).commit()

        }

    }
}
```

xml file for activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".ActivityGameStart"
    android:id="@+id/rlStart">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHighScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HIGH SCORE"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press the Start and Start the Timer"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtHighScore"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#8f0077"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtStart"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Start"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

kotlin file for fragment:

```
package com.sahil.randoms

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

class FragmentPlayArea : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ):View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_play_area, container, false)

        return view
    }
}
```

xml file for fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentPlayArea">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHighScore1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HIGH SCORE"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgTimer"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_time"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtHighScore1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTimer"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgTimer"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:textColor="#8f0077"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGuess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Guess the following Random Word!"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtHighScore1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#8f0077"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRandomWord"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ABCDE"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtGuess"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etResponse"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtRandomWord"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="40dp"
        android:hint="Enter Here"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAnswer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtRandomWord"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#8f0077"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="The Correct Word is ABCDE"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCheck"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/etResponse"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="CHECK"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/etResponse"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[screenshot of the activity before calling fragmnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2RGI.jpg)

[after calling fragment i.e. overlapped fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYy9C.jpg)

Please help me over this i am unable to solve this problem since a while :(

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: i have added now check it out.

Comment: You are placing your fragment inside a FrameLayout (`frameStart`) that is a component of your Activity's layout. So there is nothing going on that would remove the other views from the Activity layout. A Fragment doesn't replace an Activity. A Fragment is a view component that is hosted by the Activity in the Activity's view hierarchy. If you want to replace all the contents of the Activity, you should make the top level of your Activity a FrameLayout and put the fragment there. But it would make more sense to have a separate fragment for what you are wanting to swap out.

Comment: do u mean as i have used relative layout, so instead of it i should use frame layout?

Answer (score 0):

You have an Activity layout with all your text and buttons arranged in various places, and then a `FrameLayout` that fills the whole view (`match_parent` for height and width). If you put something in that FrameLayout, then you'll have all your text and buttons *plus* the new things you've just added.

If you want to do this, and the new content in the `FrameLayout` is meant to hide the other stuff, you need to do a couple of things:

- The `FrameLayout` is *below* the other views (look at how the START button is still on top) - you need to make it the last thing added to the XML file, so it's on top of everything else. Or maybe give it an `elevation` value (not sure if that works with `RelativeLayout`s but it probably does
- Your fragment layout needs a non-transparent `background` value, or you'll see the old content through it

like @Tenfour04 says, the usual way to do this is to have an Activity layout that has a content container (like the `FrameLayout`) and then you swap the UI in and out - so you'd start with a fragment containing the score and start button etc, and when you click the button it removes that fragment and adds the `FragmentPlayArea` one. That way there's nothing behind it to see! And it works better with accessibility services too (they can sometimes get stuck on the "hidden" UI), which is still there if you're just covering it up

Comment: Now i have made an activity with a container of FrameLayout but i am not able to solve the overlapping of particular container of framelayout with another fragment.
i.e. all it's UI containing view,etc, on the new one on same activity.

Comment: You use fragment transactions to put your fragment *in* the container: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions You have your first UI fragment in there, and when you want to show the next screen, you *replace* that first fragment with the second one. Search for "master/detail view" or "single activity app" to see more examples. Make sure you're not including your first fragment through XML, it's easier if you just add and remove all your fragmenrs in code